# Javascript: trouble with blur

Tags: javascript, html, blur

I'm trying to have a navigation item morph into a search bar when clicked upon, and returns to its original state when the user clicks elsewhere. The morphing's going fine but I figured 'blur' would be my best option to trigger the morphing back and it's not working.

The markup's this:

```
        <li class="navItem" id="search">Search</li>
```

and the scripting:

```
function startSearch()
{
    if(!ifSearch)
    {

        var search = document.getElementById("search");
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        var textfield = document.createElement("input");
        var submit = document.createElement("input");

        search.innerHTML = "";

        form.setAttribute("action", "search.php");
        form.setAttribute("method", "get");

        textfield.setAttribute("type", "text");
        textfield.setAttribute("id", "searchfield");
        textfield.setAttribute("name", "searchItem");

        submit.setAttribute("type", "submit");
        submit.setAttribute("id", "subSearch");

        form.appendChild(textfield);
        form.appendChild(submit);

        search.appendChild(form);

        ifSearch = true;

        search.addEventListener("blur",function() {
                  search.innerHTML = '<a>Search</a>';
                  ifSearch = false;
              });

    }
}

var ifSearch = false;

document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("click", startSearch);
```

The "blur" event never triggers. Tried "focusout" with IE and it works one time out of twenty. Not sure what's happening so I'd be really grateful if someone could enlighten me

Comment: May I see your source on jsfiddle?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/pt38j1en/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus and blur events doesn't bubble. In this case you'll need to listen for a blur event on your `<input>` field directly.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pt38j1en/6/

Comment: This is not what I said. `blur` is only triggered on the input element, it won't bubble up to the `#search` element. See http://jsfiddle.net/pt38j1en/1/

Comment: Right, I misunderstood but I tried to put the blur event on the input element and it doesn't work nonetheless

Comment: @Afunakwa Did you checked my demo... it's working. So you did something different that is not working.

Comment: @Afunakwa might've not send the right link, here it is http://jsfiddle.net/pt38j1en/6/

Comment: It works perfecty. I didn't know much about the concept of bubbling before asking the question, that's why I got confused. Thanks you